# Dijkstra's algorithm Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph

Given a graph and a source vertex in the graph, find the shortest paths from source to all vertices in the given graph.
Read more here -> [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/)

Please go through my code and help me out by pointing what's wrong with my logic.

**My code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

global INT_MAX
INT_MAX = 3 ** 38


class Graph:
    def __init__(self, numofVertices):
        self.vertList = defaultdict(list)
        self.numofVertices = numofVertices

    def addEdge(self, u, v, cost):
        self.vertList[u].append((v, cost))
        self.vertList[v].append((u, cost))

    def minDist(self, dist, visited):
        
        for v in range(self.numofVertices):
            if dist[v] < INT_MAX and v not in visited:
                minIndex = v
        return minIndex

    def dijsktra(self, src):
        dist = [INT_MAX] * self.numofVertices
        dist[src] = 0
        visited = set()

        for _ in range(self.numofVertices):
            minVertex = self.minDist(dist, visited)

            visited.add(minVertex)

            for nbr, edgeCost in self.vertList[minVertex]:
                if dist[nbr] > dist[minVertex] + edgeCost and nbr not in visited:
                    dist[nbr] = dist[minVertex] + edgeCost
        return dist


g = Graph(9)
g.addEdge(0, 1, 4)
g.addEdge(0, 7, 8)
g.addEdge(1, 7, 11)
g.addEdge(7, 8, 7)
g.addEdge(7, 6, 1)
g.addEdge(7, 1, 11)
g.addEdge(1, 2, 8)
g.addEdge(2, 3, 7)
g.addEdge(2, 5, 4)
g.addEdge(2, 8, 2)
g.addEdge(6, 8, 6)
g.addEdge(6, 5, 2)
g.addEdge(5, 2, 4)
g.addEdge(5, 3, 14)
g.addEdge(5, 4, 10)
g.addEdge(3, 4, 9)
print(g.dijsktra(0))
```

**Current Output:**

```
[0, 4, 15, 25, 21, 11, 9, 8, 15] # Index represents the vertex
```

**Expected Output**

```
[0, 4, 12, 19, 21, 11, 9, 8 ,14]
```

**Here's the graph we are solving:**
[image]

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 OP provided his code,  the expected output, and his output.  IMHO, there is nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: wow, I spent hours writing the code and whiteboarding and this guy is saying I asked without researching anyway, drank some coffee and fixed it. Answering it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the function that checks the min distance, We need to update the current max so that we can compare it with other unvisited vertices and see if another vertex exists with a lesser value.

```
def minDist(self, dist, visited):
    max1 = 3 ** 38
    minIndex = 0
    for v in range(self.numofVertices):
        if dist[v] < max1 and v not in visited:
            max1 = dist[v]
            minIndex = v
    return minIndex
```

Comment: While I think this answer may suffice, I think it might be helpful for someone else facing the problem to be given more insight about how you arrived at solution. See if you can add more details in the answer. By the way, kudos for get the solution yourself.

Comment: sure will do it after my lecture! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in `minDist` method. It returns the index of first adjacent index, not the one with minimal distance.

This function should look like:

```
def minDist(self, dist, visited):
    m = INT_MAX
    for v in range(self.numofVertices):
        if dist[v] < m and v not in visited:
            m = dist[v]
            minIndex = v 
    return minIndex
```

Also, I am not sure that you have to assign both `vertList[u]` and `vertList[v]` in `addEdge`.

Comment: Its because the edges are undirected, or let's just say they are bidirectional.